# Why isn't the tqdm progress bar showing up on my csv reader loop?

Tags: python, tqdm

I have tried doing it a few different ways, but none have worked so far within my code. I end up breaking my script so it just shows an empty progress and the script ends instead of actually doing what it is supposed to. How do I properly add a tqdm progress bar to this part of my script?

```
def add_column_in_csv(input_file, output_file, transform_row):
    # open input file and create output file
    with open(input_file, 'r') as read_obj, \
        open(output_file, 'wb') as write_obj:
        # create a csv.reader object from the input file object
        csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
        # create a csv.writer object from the output file object
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        lines = len(list(read_obj))
        print lines
        # read each row of the input csv file as list
        for row in tqdm(csv_reader, total=len(list(read_obj))):
            # append the headers and values from checks in add_to_row
            transform_row(row, csv_reader.line_num)
            # add the updated row to the output file
            csv_writer.writerow(row)


# let them know it is doing something
print('Analyzing input file . . .')
# actually add the data to the new csv here
add_column_in_csv(input_file, output_file, add_to_row)
# it is done
print('Done analyzing file. Output created: ' + str(output_file))
```

Doing it like this it seemingly doesn't execute my code within the for loop. It shows a progress bar at 0% that does not progress and says 0/17 (which is the number of rows in my csv) and then prints my last line 'Done analyzing file. Output created:', but the output csv is blank. However, if I remove the total=len(list(read_obj)) altogether the script does run and at least shows the number of iterations happening and how long it took, but no progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for row in tqdm(csv_reader, total=len(read_obj.read().split('\n'))):
    # append the headers and values from checks in add_to_row
            transform_row(row, csv_reader.line_num)
            # add the updated row to the output file
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because an object type of file doesn't have a len(). However, I tried something similar where I did total=len(list(read_obj)), but in doing this the bulk of my script doesn't actually run as it only prints out a progress bar of 0% and is finished. It seems to basically ignore the lines in the for loop for some reason that I don't quite understand.

Comment: I assume that is because list read_obj doesn't split the file into lines, so try the updated method, where you use the length of the list when the file is split by new line

Comment: I am pretty sure the list works fine because if I do lines = len(list(read_obj)) and print lines it outputs the number of rows in the file. My main issue is that the script isn't running fully whenever I add something above or in the for loop. The actual loop doesn't run for some reason.

Comment: Is your import statement `from tqdm import tqdm`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I edited my code in the initial post with more context as it is probably worth noting that the csv portion is its own function that I am calling

Comment: do you have any idea why it seemingly doesn't execute my code within the for loop? It shows a progress bar at 0% and says 0/17 (which is the number of rows in my csv) and then does my last line 'Done analyzing file. Output created', but the output csv is blank.